# Future method throwing error

Tags: apex, future

We have a future class which will call future class to send mail. Sometimes I get this mail from salesforce.

**Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 005A00000062Q6O/00DA0000000YXoL
Failed to invoke future method 'public static void sendEmail(Set)' on class 'AsyncApexClass' for job id '707A000004xKn9u'
caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, From: invalid email address: 'Certification Support' <test@external.abc.com>: [From__c]
Class.AsyncApexClass.sendEmail: line 43, column 1**

Below is my future class:

```
    global class AsyncApexClass{
@future

public static void sendEmail(Set<Id> sendList){
List <Notes__c> notesList = new List<Notes__c>();
notesList.clear();
for(List<EmailMessage> emailmsglist:[select Id,parentId,Parent.Email__c,Parent.Contact.Email,ToAddress, FromAddress, Subject, TextBody, HTMLBody, CreatedDate from EmailMessage where id in :sendList] )
{
        for(EmailMessage emlist :emailmsglist){

             Notes__c note= new Notes__c(); // Create a note object 
             note.Case__c= emlist.parentid;
                 IF (emlist.HTMLBody != NULL && emlist.HTMLBody != ''){
                 note.Message__c = emlist.HTMLBody;
                 }
                 else {
                 note.Message__c = emlist.TextBody;
                 }    
             note.Sent_To__c = emlist.ToAddress;
             note.From__c = emlist.FromAddress;
             note.Subject__c = emlist.Subject;
             note.Datetime_Created__c = emlist.CreatedDate;
             if (emlist.Parent.Contact.Email == emlist.ToAddress || emlist.Parent.Email__c == emlist.ToAddress) // If the email is the same as Case's contact email or Email__c on Case itself, the type is a response.
             {
             note.Type__c = 'Response';
             }
             else {
             note.Type__c = 'Forward/Others';
             }
             notesList.add(note); // Add note object to the list
         }
}
// If the note list has records, insert the list.
if(notesList.size()>0) {
       insert notesList;
       }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is due to what Salesforce interprets as valid address. From this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170904&language=en_US&type=1)

> For the local part of the email address we accept the following
>   characters. The local part is anything before the @ sign.
>
> abcdefg.hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#$%&'*/=?^_+-`{|}~0123456789
>
> Note: The character dot “.” is supported; provided that it is not the
>   first character in the local-part
>
> For the domain part of the email address we accept. The domain part is
>   anything after the @ in an email address:
>
> 0-9 and A-Z and a-z and dash “-“
>
> Example email address: 
>   abcdefg.hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#$%&'*/=?^_+-`{|}~0123456789@acme-inc.com

The following  `note.From__c = emlist.FromAddress;` is storing a wrong format (accordign to salesforce) i.e. `test@external.abc.com`.

Comment: I changed the email format as per your suggestion. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question with your error?